# Port Forwarding How to access from external ip

Tags: port-forwarding

I can access the home page of the router on port 80. I have the server listening on 8080. I am able to use the http://www.canyouseeme.org/ to see the ip and port and another web site which pings to see if the ip and port is open also works.

But when I am trying to call from browser it is not connecting. I can connect from 10.x.x.xx:8080 within the home network from any of the device but not using the external ip.

Comment: You need to configure [NAT](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) on your router.

Comment: NAT may not be necessary if he's just forwarding traffic from his external to a single port. Port forwarding should be enough

Comment: Which machine are you using to try and access the server using its external ip ? If it's a machine within your network, it might be that your router doesn't support hairpin NAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To verify... You want to enter the external IP on an internal box and have the port forward work. Ultimately you can use the same URL internally and externally.

If that's a correct explanation of what you're looking for, your router/firewall needs to support NAT reflection. I don't know if there's a standard term for that function, but that's what it's called on my pfSense firewall.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback

Comment: You are right. I tried from outside..things are good.

Comment: Yup, NAT reflection is your problem then. Depending on your firewall, it may or may not be supported. The great Google should be able to tell you if your device supports it and how to enable it.